# How to Create Parameter types

Tags: .net, vb.net, parameters

I want to determine specific parameters for a function and when I'm call the function with parameters Visual Studio to list availible parameters.

To do this I generally use a code like This

```
Private Function SomeFunctionName(ParaType as string)

if Paratype = "Method1"
'Works gets done in a specific way

elseif Paratype = "Method2"
'The Other Way

end if

end function


Sub New()
SomeFunctionName("Method1")

end sub
```

Is there a more sensible way to refer Method1?

Thanks for Your Help :)

Comment: You should use an `Enum` rather than `Strings`, because then you are limited to only valid values and you get full Intellisense and compile-time support. Beyond that, your description is too vague to know whether you could improve things further.

Comment: Apparently Enum is the exact thing I'am looking for. Thank you so much.